# Why when i run a python file using call() from subprocess i get ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.8

so im making a flappy bird game and everytime player dies i close the program and run it again:

```
call(["python", "app.py"])
quit(1)
```

whenever `call(["python", "app.py"])` runs i get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'` 
even though i have pygame installed.

app.py:

```
import pygame as py
from subprocess import call



# Initialize Pygame
py.init()
# Window
icon = py.image.load(('flappyicon.jpg'))
window = py.display.set_mode((800, 600))
window.fill((155, 152, 13))
py.display.set_caption('Flappy Bird')
py.display.set_icon(icon)

# Player
playerImg = py.image.load('flappy.png')
playerImg = py.transform.scale(playerImg, (45, 45))
playerY = 250
playerX = 30
# Player Physics
playerYDownVelocity = 0


def player(playerX, playerY):
    window.blit(playerImg, (playerX, playerY))


# Game Loop
lost = False
running = True
while running:
    window.fill((155, 152, 13))
    for event in py.event.get():
        if event.type == py.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == py.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == py.K_SPACE:
                playerYDownVelocity = -0.4

            if event.key == py.K_r:
                if lost == True:
                    print('elooor')
                    rerun = 'app.py'
                    call(["python", "app.py"])
                    quit(1)

    if playerY >= 550:
        # gameOver()
        lost = True
        playerY = 550
    elif playerY <= 0:
        playerY = 0

    # Physics
    playerYDownVelocity += 0.001
    playerY += playerYDownVelocity
    player(playerX, playerY)
    py.display.update()
```

when i run it from pycharm it works. I googled for it but i could not found anything.

Comment: It may be that the python version/environment in which your original runs (pycharm) differs from that of the `call(["python","app"])` .  Pycharm can run using virtualenv and/or may be using a different python version than the bare call.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so two things

> 1. first if you are making this game withing a virtual environment(and you most definitely should, make sure pygame is installed withing that virtual environment, otherwise it is just installed globally in your system and not in your virtual environment and that is the most likely reason for that error
> 2. two, you should consider using `Popen()` instead of `call()` but this part is just a friendly suggestion